# Build Phonegap error

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I'm trying to create a build for Android by [Adobe](https://build.phonegap.com/) site, but I get the following error: "`/project/assets/www/app_ponto/platforms/ios/Marcação de ponto: error: Invalid directory name, unable to add.`".

When I try to create the build via local CLI, it works normally.

I've tried looking for this folder, however do not think.

This was the project name "Marcação de ponto", however the project name was changed to "ponto".

Here is the complete error:

```
Build Date: 2016-08-01 16:35:23 +0000
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PLUGIN OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-battery-status@~1.1.1" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-battery-status" at "1.1.2" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-camera@~2.1.1" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-camera" at "2.1.1" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-media-capture@~1.2.0" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-media-capture" at "1.2.0" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-file" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-file" at "4.2.0" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-compat" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-compat" at "1.0.0" for android

The Android Persistent storage location now defaults to "Internal". Please check this plugins README to see if you application needs any changes in its config.xml.

If this is a new application no changes are required.

If this is an update to an existing application that did not specify an "AndroidPersistentFileLocation" you may need to add:

      "<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />"

to config.xml in order for the application to find previously stored files.
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-console@~1.0.2" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-console" at "1.0.3" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-contacts@~2.0.1" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-contacts" at "2.0.1" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-device@~1.1.1" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-device" at "1.1.2" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-device-motion@~1.2.0" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-device-motion" at "1.2.1" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-device-orientation@~1.0.2" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-device-orientation" at "1.0.3" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-dialogs@~1.2.0" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-dialogs" at "1.2.1" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-file@~4.1.1" via npm
Plugin "cordova-plugin-file" already installed on android. Making it top-level.
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-file-transfer@~1.5.0" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-file-transfer" at "1.5.1" for android
Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-file" already installed on android.
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-geolocation@~2.1.0" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-geolocation" at "2.1.0" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-globalization@~1.0.3" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-globalization" at "1.0.3" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@~1.3.0" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" at "1.3.0" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-media@~2.2.0" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-media" at "2.2.0" for android
Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-file" already installed on android.
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-network-information@~1.2.0" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-network-information" at "1.2.1" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-splashscreen@~3.2.1" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" at "3.2.2" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-statusbar@~2.1.2" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-statusbar" at "2.1.3" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-vibration@~2.1.0" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-vibration" at "2.1.1" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist@~1.2.1" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" at "1.2.2" for android

               This plugin is only applicable for versions of cordova-android greater than 4.0. If you have a previous platform version, you do *not* need this plugin since the whitelist will be built in.
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-compat@1.0.0" via npm
Plugin "cordova-plugin-compat" already installed on android. Making it top-level.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
COMPILE OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Executing: ant debug -f /project/build.xml
Buildfile: /project/build.xml
Buildfile: /project/build.xml

-check-env:

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 25.1.7

-setup:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 25.1.7

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: .app_ponto
     [echo] Project Name: .app_ponto
  [gettype] Project Type: Application
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-pre-clean:

clean:

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getlibpath] Library dependencies:
[getlibpath] 
[getlibpath] ------------------
[getlibpath] Ordered libraries:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 23.0.1
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for .app_ponto...

nodeps:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 25.1.7

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: .app_ponto
  [gettype] Project Type: Android Library

-pre-clean:

clean:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 5.1.1
[gettarget] API level:        22
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/bin
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/bin/res
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/bin/rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/bin/rsLibs
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/gen
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/bin/classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/bin/dexedLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for .app_ponto...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] Ordered libraries:
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...

nodeps:

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 25.1.7

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: .app_ponto
  [gettype] Project Type: Android Library

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 23.0.1
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for .app_ponto...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 5.1.1
[gettarget] API level:        22
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/CordovaLib/res
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/CordovaLib/libs
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/CordovaLib/bin
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/CordovaLib/bin/res
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/CordovaLib/bin/rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/CordovaLib/bin/rsLibs
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/CordovaLib/gen
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/CordovaLib/bin/classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/CordovaLib/bin/dexedLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for .app_ponto...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] Generating BuildConfig class.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 36 source files to /project/CordovaLib/bin/classes
    [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
     [echo] Creating library output jar file...
      [jar] Building jar: /project/CordovaLib/bin/classes.jar

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
     [echo] Library project: do not convert bytecode...

-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: /project/CordovaLib/res
   [crunch] To destination dir: /project/CordovaLib/bin/res
   [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache

-package-resources:
     [echo] Library project: do not package resources...

-package:
     [echo] Library project: do not package apk...

-post-package:

-do-debug:
     [echo] Library project: do not create apk...
[propertyfile] Creating new property file: /project/CordovaLib/bin/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /project/CordovaLib/bin/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /project/CordovaLib/bin/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /project/CordovaLib/bin/build.prop

-post-build:

debug:

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] Generating BuildConfig class.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 52 source files to /project/bin/classes
    [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
      [dex] input: /project/bin/classes
      [dex] input: /project/CordovaLib/bin/classes.jar
      [dex] Pre-Dexing /project/CordovaLib/bin/classes.jar -> classes-c87d23dfbd8bfc098047cc3a864ea585.jar
      [dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into /project/bin/classes.dex...
       [dx] Merged dex A (161 defs/258.3KiB) with dex B (83 defs/103.9KiB). Result is 244 defs/440.6KiB. Took 0.3s

-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: /project/res
   [crunch] To destination dir: /project/bin/res
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /project/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_action_next_item.png => /project/bin/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_action_next_item.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /project/bin/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_action_next_item.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /project/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_action_previous_item.png => /project/bin/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_action_previous_item.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /project/bin/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_action_previous_item.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /project/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_action_remove.png => /project/bin/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_action_remove.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /project/bin/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_action_remove.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /project/res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png => /project/bin/res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /project/bin/res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png: 67% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /project/res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png => /project/bin/res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /project/bin/res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /project/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_action_next_item.png => /project/bin/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_action_next_item.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /project/bin/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_action_next_item.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /project/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_action_previous_item.png => /project/bin/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_action_previous_item.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /project/bin/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_action_previous_item.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /project/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_action_remove.png => /project/bin/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_action_remove.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /project/bin/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_action_remove.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /project/res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png => /project/bin/res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /project/bin/res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /project/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_action_next_item.png => /project/bin/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_action_next_item.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /project/bin/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_action_next_item.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /project/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_action_previous_item.png => /project/bin/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_action_previous_item.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /project/bin/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_action_previous_item.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /project/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_action_remove.png => /project/bin/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_action_remove.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /project/bin/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_action_remove.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /project/res/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png => /project/bin/res/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /project/bin/res/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png: 53% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /project/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_action_next_item.png => /project/bin/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_action_next_item.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /project/bin/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_action_next_item.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /project/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_action_previous_item.png => /project/bin/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_action_previous_item.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /project/bin/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_action_previous_item.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /project/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_action_remove.png => /project/bin/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_action_remove.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /project/bin/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_action_remove.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Crunched 16 PNG files to update cache

-package-resources:
     [aapt] Creating full resource package...
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.gitignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping dir '.gradle' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.jshintrc' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.travis.yml' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.travis.yml' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.jshintrc' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.jscs.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.ratignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.jshintignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.jshintrc' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.jshintrc' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.travis.yml' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.travis.yml' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.travis.yml' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.travis.yml' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.travis.yml' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.travis.yml' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.jshintrc' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.travis.yml' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.documentup.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.gitignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.travis.yml' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.travis.yml' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.jshintrc' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.jscs.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.ratignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.jshintignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.jshintrc' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.jshintrc' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.travis.yml' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.jshintrc' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.travis.yml' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.documentup.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.mailmap' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.travis.yml' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.travis.yml' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.travis.yml' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.travis.yml' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.travis.yml' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.travis.yml' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping dir '.github' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.travis.yml' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.jshintrc' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.travis.yml' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.documentup.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.gitignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.travis.yml' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.travis.yml' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.jshintrc' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.jshintrc' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.travis.yml' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.travis.yml' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.eslintignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.travis.yml' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.jshintrc' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping dir '.idea' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt] /project/assets/www/app_ponto/platforms/ios/Marcação de ponto: error: Invalid directory name, unable to add.

BUILD FAILED
/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:928: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:946: null returned: 1

Total time: 16 seconds

/project/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                    ^
Error code 1 for command: ant with args: debug,-f,/project/build.xml

/project/assets/www/app_ponto/platforms/ios/Marcação de ponto: error: Invalid directory name, unable to add.
PORTUGUÊS
/ Projecto / ativos / www / app_ponto / plataformas / ios / Marcação de ponto: erro: nome de diretório inválido, incapaz de acrescentar.
OPÇÕES DE EXTENSÃOMAIS »
```

Thank's for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the special old project name characters. Plumb after changing the project name, the folder with his name were there.
The solution was to remove IOS support and add again with the following commands:

```
cordova platform remove ios

cordova platform add ios
```